# Laravel 4 --JOINS-- Combining two tables to retrieve the names of the multiple agents in an entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need a Laravel 4 join statement.

The images below depicts the two tables I have and the one I need.

[image]

I need to use both tables to retrieve user A's and UserB's names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$trades=  DB::select("select trades.id, u.userA_user_name, uu.userB_user_name, trades.time, trades.currency  

    from trades 

    left join 
        (
           select id, user_name as `userA_user_name` from users
         ) u on u.id = trades.userA

    left join 
         (
              select id, user_name as `userB_user_name` from users
          ) uu on uu.id = trades.userB");
```

**If you need to bind a parameter:**

```
 $trade=  DB::select("select trades.id, u.userA_user_name, uu.userB_user_name, trades.time, trades.currency  

        from trades 

        left join 
            (
               select id, user_name as `userA_user_name` from users
             ) u on u.id = trades.userA

        left join 
             (
                  select id, user_name as `userB_user_name` from users
              ) uu on uu.id = trades.userB

        where trades.id = ?", array(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe will help:

```
$query = new User; // Your model name. (tablename = users)
$query = $query->join('trades', 'users.trade_id', '=', 'trades.id');

$query = $query->where('users.mail', '=', 'some@mail'); // not necessarily
$query = $query->where('trades.userA', '=', 'some_user'); // not necessarily

$result = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5); // or $query->get();
```